# Can i make a form, based on a query? As in a form from different fields/tables within my database

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

from the title, you can probably tell i'm an amateur. However, i would like to create a form for my MySQL/ php site, which requires fields from different tables throughout my DB. Is this possible? or do i need to create a table with all the neccessary fields in it?

Also, isit possible to save the output of this form and view all the outputs upon requested?

Thanks in advance.

ask any questions if i left anything out. I kept it short as I think this may be a simple question :@!

really appreciate it.

Comment: A table in your database has no relation at all to the PHP code or form rendered in HTML, so there is no need for a 1:1 form to table setup. The form you show your user can have any fields it in you want, and when you receive the form POST in PHP, your application logic must then place the fields into the correct tables.

Comment: Yes, that's a simple question. But it may require more tutoring than is on-topic here. Can you be more specific? With database table structures? Or envisioned forms? At the very least post some code of what you tried.

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: In fact, the database has no idea that the PHP code or HTML markup exist. All it knows are the commands it receives (from your PHP code)

Comment: but if i wanted to view the results of the form, which is coming from atleast 3 different tables, how would i do this? surely the outcome will have to be posted into one table?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can! PHP use the function `echo` to print data to the HTML page. this mean that you can read from the DB first and using `IF` to print different HTML form.

**for example(Pseudo Code):**

```
$in=getFrom(DB);

if($in['key']=="value")
{
    echo ".....specific HTML....... ";
}
else
{
     echo ".....alternative HTML....... ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure i understood your question correctly but..

If you want to combine data from different tables you want to perform a database query with a [JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

for example, if you have one table with people and one table with their pets you can combine this data in the same output by writing :

```
select * from persons 
left outer join pets on (pets.person_id = persons.id)
```

Now, if you want to "save this output" you should create a [VIEW](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html)

```
create view persons_and_their_pets as 
    (
    select * from persons 
    left outer join pets on (pets.person_id = persons.id)
    )
```

you are now able to access this data via:

```
select * from persons_and_their_pets
```